# How to run Velo Code (Open Lightbox) from Custom HTML and Javascript Code in Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I am currently building a website with Wix Studio in which I get some data from an external database which I displayed on a table. On one of the colomns named 'Select Box', I wrote custom javascript code (because I was unable to use velo because it didn't treat each cell in the table as an independent entity) to replace the values gotten from the database (Yes and NO) with either checked or unchecked checkbox respectively, and a button froma dropdown `<a href="#">Get more information about this vehicle</a>` which when clicked, I am supposed to open a lightbox (already created in wix studio editor) 'Carlist Lightbox'. How can I open the lightbox using my custom javascript code which was running on the client side?

[Link to the webpage](https://www.tptxdev.com/carlist)
*Below is the full content of the custom code written as related to this issue*

```
<script>
  function updateSelect() {
    var selectColumns = document.querySelectorAll("tbody td:nth-child(1)");
    Array.from(selectColumns).forEach(function (selectColumn) {
      var value = selectColumn.innerText;
      if (selectColumn.innerHTML.includes("<style")) {
      } else {
        if (value == "Yes") {
          selectColumn.innerHTML = `
          <style>
      .custom-checkbox {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .custom-checkbox input {
        display: none;
      }

      .checkmark {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .custom-checkbox input:checked + .checkmark:after {
        content: "✔️";
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown container */
      .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown button */
      .dropbtn {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown content */
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown items */
      .dropdown-content a {
        padding: 12px 16px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
      }

      /* Change color on hover */
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="checkDiv" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0;  margin: auto; padding-top: 30px">
            <div style:"display: block; margin:auto; padding: 28px">
                <label class="custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" checked /> <!-- Set 'checked' attribute -->
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropdown()">▼</button>

                  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                    /* Onclick of the link below, a lightbox (Carlist Lightbox from the wix studio)            is supposed to pop up  */
                    <a href="#">Get more information about this vehicle</a>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

 `;
        } else {
          selectColumn.innerHTML = `

          <style>

      .custom-checkbox {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .custom-checkbox input {
        display: none;
      }

      .checkmark {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .custom-checkbox input:checked + .checkmark:after {
        content: "✔️";
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown container */
      .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown button */
      .dropbtn {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown content */
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      /* Style for the dropdown items */
      .dropdown-content a {
        padding: 12px 16px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
      }

      /* Change color on hover */
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
    </style>

          <div id="checkDiv" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0;  margin: auto; padding-top: 30px">
            <div style:"display: block; margin:auto; padding: 28px">
      <label class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="toggleDropdown()">▼</button>

        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
          /* Onclick of the link below, a lightbox (Carlist Lightbox from the wix studio)            is supposed to pop up  */
                    <a href="#">Get more information about this vehicle</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
            `;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  updateSelect();

  // JavaScript function to toggle the visibility of the dropdown content
  function toggleDropdown() {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector(".custom-checkbox input");
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    var dropdownContent = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    dropdownContent.style.display =
      dropdownContent.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
  }

  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
          openDropdown.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("checkDiv").addEventListener("click", function () {
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    });

    // Prevent checkbox click event from propagating to the document click event
    document
      .querySelector(".custom-checkbox")
      .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
  });
</script>
```

I have tried importing the wix mode #

```
<script type="module">
    import wix from "wix";
  
    wixWindow.openLightbox('Carlist Lightbox');
</script>
```

But I keep on getting weild errors that module `wix` is not found.
I also tried opening the lightbox directly without importing wix.     `wixWindowFrontend.openLightbox("Carlist Lightbox", urlYearMakeModelTradeMarket);`   but it still didn't work.